# Tune up `fiddler auto responder rule editor` to make him able to match post request with some specific body content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fiddler, fiddlercore

Do you know how to tune up `fiddler auto responder rule editor`  to make him able to match post request with some specific body content, not the url path. E.g i want to match all request which contains in theirs bodies command with name `BillingCreate`

[image: Post body]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `URLWithBody:` prefix in your Match condition, like so:

`URLWithBody:upload.php TextToFindInBody`

Comment: What does upload.php part means  ?

Comment: It's a partial URL to which you want to limit the action.